# Message queue IPC error: Invalid Argument

Tags: c, linux, queue, ipc, args

I'm trying to create a message queue between two processes. The problem is that I'm getting this error ("Invalid argument") when running the client program, although I am not receiving any compilation warnings.

[image]

Does anyone know why the debugger refers to files and commands, like write, that I am not even using?
How can I make this error disappear and establish communication?
What am I missing?

P.S: Here is the client's code :

```
#include"v1.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int mqid;
    struct request req;
    
    
    key_t key=ftok("/home/Desktop/as3/v1/v1s.c",65); 
    mqid=msgget(key,0666);
    req.msg="first stage";
    do{
        msgsnd(mqid,&req,sizeof(struct request),0);
        perror("client:");
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}//end of main()
//do i need sth like an ip for an arg ?
```